# Loss of floating point values :: reading JSON with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

In the project, the program reads JSON Document (using rapidjson) and then takes a part of that JSON document and tries to create new JSON Value. Following code is used for that

```cpp
# jsonstring is the JSON string
rapidjson::Document firstJSON = readJsonString(jsonstring);
# val is the Value which is a small part of firstJSON document
rapidjson::Value &val = firstJSON["A"]["B"];
```

**jsonstring** is a follows

```json
{
    "A":
    {
       "B":
       {
           "e0":0.03974359855055809,
           "e1":0.17799679934978486
       }
    }
    "R": "stringval"
}
```

so value of **Val** should be

```json
"B":
{
  "e0":0.03974359855055809,
  "e1":0.17799679934978486
}
```

but it is giving me this output: **Val**

```json
"B":
{
  "e0":0.0,
  "e1":0.1
}
```

So clearly when trying to read a part of json from Document and reading it in rapidjson::Value, it is just taking single decimal value.

Can anyone please tell me how to read from rapidjson::Document and make rapidjson::Value with Double precision of values ?

**Things have tried.**

1. Tried to set the precision, but I didn't get a way to set precision for `reading from rapidjson::Document to rapidjson::Value`

Thank you so much !!

Comment: How do you get this output?

Comment: @Botje sorry, the precision was set at 1, thats the reason I was getting this output.So set the precision to 18 and Issue is solved. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted OP's comment to an answer:

> The precision was set at 1, that's the reason you are getting this output. So set the precision to 18 and this issue should be solved.